# Make a sprite go to a certain position depending on the sprite's current position?

Tags: ios, if-statement, ios7, sprite-kit, sprite

I think my title is rather confusing but I'm not really sure how to title it. Here is my current code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
SKAction *moveNodeRight = [SKAction moveByX:-209.0 y:0.0 duration:0.85];
 [_squirrelSprite runAction: moveNodeRight withKey:@"changeside"];
//_squirrelSprite.xScale = -1.0;

if(_squirrelSprite.xScale == -1.0)
{
    _squirrelSprite.xScale = 1.0;
} else {
    _squirrelSprite.xScale = -1.0;
}
}
```

When I tap the screen the sprite moves to a new position (X:-209.0, Y:0.0). The new position is to the left of the current position. When I tap the screen a second time, the sprite just moves farther left off of the screen.

What I want: I'm happy with what I have so far, but when the sprite is at the new position (X:-209.0, Y:0.0), I want the second tap to return it to it's original position. I think it would look something like the above code, but so far nothing is working. Below is an idea of what it could possibly look like. Thank you!

```
if(_squirrelSprite.position == the second position)
{
    _squirrelSprite.position = the first position;
} else {
    _squirrelSprite.xScale = the second position;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This moves a node from one position to another when the user taps the screen. It then moves the node back to the original position when the user taps the screen again.

```
@interface MyScene()

@property SKSpriteNode *squirrelSprite;
@property BOOL atFirstPosition;
@property CGPoint firstPosition;

@end

@implementation MyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        _firstPosition = CGPointMake(300, self.frame.size.height/2);
        _squirrelSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(32, 32)];
        _squirrelSprite.position = _firstPosition;
        _atFirstPosition = YES;
        [self addChild:_squirrelSprite];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (_atFirstPosition)
    {
        SKAction *moveNodeLeft = [SKAction moveByX:-209.0 y:0.0 duration:0.85];
        [_squirrelSprite runAction: moveNodeLeft withKey:@"changeside"];
    } else {
        _squirrelSprite.position = _firstPosition;
    }
    _atFirstPosition = !_atFirstPosition;
    _squirrelSprite.xScale *= -1.0;
}

@end
```

**EDIT:**
This moves the node back to its original position using an SKAction

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (_atFirstPosition)
    {
        SKAction *moveNodeLeft = [SKAction moveByX:-209.0 y:0.0 duration:0.85];
        [_squirrelSprite runAction: moveNodeLeft withKey:@"moveleft"];
    } else {
        SKAction *moveNodeRight = [SKAction moveByX:209.0 y:0.0 duration:0.85];
        [_squirrelSprite runAction: moveNodeRight withKey:@"moveright"];
    }
    _atFirstPosition = !_atFirstPosition;
    _squirrelSprite.xScale *= -1.0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks great! I'm going to mess around with it so it fits my current code.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is a way to add a duration to the sprite moving back to the original position like it does when it originally moves? Other than that it's perfect, thank you. :)

Comment: You're welcome. You can use another SKAction to move the node back to its original position. I've edited my answer to include code to do that.